# How to convert a java class which use command line argument to use in android?

Tags: java, android, command-line-arguments

I am having a problem with a java class which use command line argument and I have to use this class in my android app. 
My problem is that how can I pass the argument in android or any other way to use this file in android app by manually entering arguments?

**This is the JAVA class which I have to use in android :**

```
public class VideoListExample 
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ParameterHelper helper = new ParameterHelper(args);
            args = helper.getRemainingArgs();
            if(args.length > 2) {
                printUsage();
                System.exit(1);
                return;
            }

            String titleSearch = null;
            if(args.length == 2) {
                titleSearch = args[1];
            }

            Vzaar vzaar = helper.createVzaar();

            VideoListRequest request = new VideoListRequest(args[0]);
            request.setPage(1);
            request.setSize(true);
            request.setCount(100);
            request.setSortAscending(true);
            request.setTitleSearch(titleSearch);

            List<Video> videoList = null;
            while(!(videoList = vzaar.getVideoList(request)).isEmpty()) 
            {
                for(Video video : videoList) {
                    System.out.println(
                        "ID=" + video.getId() +
                        ", Created=" + video.getCreatedAt() +
                        ", Size=" + video.getWidth() + "x" + video.getHeight() +
                        ", Duration=" + video.getDuration() + "s" +
                        ", Play Count=" + video.getPlayCount() +
                        ", URL=" + video.getUrl() +
                        ", Title=" + video.getTitle());
                }

                if(videoList.size() < 100) break;
                request.setPage(request.getPage() + 1);
            }
        }
        catch(VzaarException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(2);
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            printUsage();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            printUsage();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private static final  void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("Usage: vzaar-list " +
            ParameterHelper.getCommonCommandLineArgs() + 
            " <username> [<title-search>]\n");
        System.out.println("Params:");
        System.out.println("   <username>          " +
        "The user name to fetch active videos for");
        System.out.println("   <title-search>      " +
            "Return only videos with title containing given string");
        System.out.println(ParameterHelper.getCommonCommandLineHelp());
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

**and the arguments should be pass in this manner :**

```
java_class [-debug] [-ssl3] [-transport hc3|hc4] [-url <url>] [-oatoken <token>] [-oasecret <secret>] <username> [<title-search>]
```

**and I have to pass only these three arguments :**

```
java_class [-oatoken <token>] [-oasecret <secret>] <username>
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you will have to create a UI where the user can enter all the values.

Then add a button that converts those values into a `String` array and which calls `main()`

A more clean solution would be to copy the strings into a new "config" object and have the button fill out the same config object. Then, you can write a method which takes the config object as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a better way, but I think the following will be an easy and fast solution:

Firstly, give an appropriate name for your `main` function. Then use varargs instead of `String` array as argument. Also, throw an exception of appropriate type if you encounter  invalid arguments(`IllegalArgumentException`, for example).

So, rewrite `main` as

```
public static void listVideos(String ... args) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Also, replace `System.exit(1)` with

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arguments!");
```

Now, you can reuse the code as:

```
VideoListExample.listVideos("-oatoken", "<token>", 
                            "-oasecret", "<secret>", "<username>");
```